# How can i make it show the bottom of this element? (HTML, CSS, JS)

Tags: javascript, sockets, socket.io

I want users to be able to see message that are sent after, which they cant see cause it runs out of room and i dont want the element to constantly expand so it wont ruin/destroy over elements.

How can i make this show the what is being sent after AA? https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLXvv.png

using Socket.io, jquery, js, html and css.

```html
<!-- code -->
<div style="float:right;margin-right:3%; height:550px;">
  <ul id="messages" style="height: 85%;"></ul>
      <form action="" style="">
        <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /> <button class="btn-primary">Send</button>
      </form>
  </center>
</div>

<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(function () {
    var socket = io();
    $('form').submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault(); // prevents page reloading
      socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
      $('#m').val('');
      return false;
    });
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
      $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all the data to be visible vertically you must add

**CSS**

```
overflow-y : scroll;
```

to your `ul`.

After that for the smooth motion for the scroll down after the data inserted 
add the animation as

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input").keyup(function(){
 $('ul').animate({scrollTop: '100%'}, 800);
  });
});
```

Comment: That makes the elements invisible.

Comment: ok can you share the code on jsfiddle or something by which i can edit the answer after running it?

Comment: Sure, their is a live version at: https://music.avexcodes.repl.co/
and the code i just pushed to my repo: https://github.com/AvexCodes/music/

Comment: Do you want it to be scroll able?

Comment: yes, but i also want it to automatically move down as new messages are sent, if that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to add a scrollbar to your chat box,

```
<!-- code -->
<div style="float:right;margin-right:3%; height:550px; ">
  <ul id="messages" style="height: 85%;overflow-y: scroll;"></ul>
      <form action="" style="">
        <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /> <button class="btn-primary">Send</button>
      </form>
  </center>
</div>

<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(function () {
    var socket = io();
    $('form').submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault(); // prevents page reloading
      socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
      $('#m').val('');
      return false;
    });
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
      $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
    });
  });
</script>
```

This will give you something that looks like this:

[image: picture of chat box with scroll bar]

Comment: Do you want it to auto-scroll down @Avex ?

Comment: I updated the code, to what you said but a scroll bar doesn't seem to appear? (When it reaches its max size)

Comment: Yes @Nicolasome

Comment: My bad @Avex, I added the overflow css in the wrong place, I just updated the code so the scroll bar should appear now. I'll add the auto scrolling for you

Comment: Thank you, but how can i make it automatically scroll down as new messages are sent?